# If a student earns a non-ABET accredited engineering degree, when can they take the FE or PE exam?

Tags: usa, engineering-mathematics

I just recently had a student (U.S. university) ask "How long would I have to wait until I could be eligible to take the FE or PE exam if I earned a non-ABET accredited engineering degree?" The student is looking to transfer, and I could not answer his question. I tried looking it up on the NCEES and ABET website, but I couldn't find a clear answer. Any answers or resources would be greatly appreciated.

FE = Fundamentals of Engineering
PE = Principles and Practice of Engineering
ABET = Accreditation Board for Engineering and Technology
NCEES = National Council of Examiners for Engineering and Surveying

Comment: Thank you, I have added clarification

Comment: From https://fundamentalsofengineering.com/mod/page/view.php?id=26#:~:text=In%20that%20case%2C%20you%20will,of%20experience%20for%20the%20F.E. : "If you are not enrolled in an ABET-accredited B.E. program, you will require six years of experience for the F.E. exam and 12 years for the P.E. exam."

Comment: Professional engineering licensure is done at the state level. Different states may have slightly different policies regarding graduates of non-accredited programs. Please add a state tag. EDIT: it appears that the common locations do not exist in this stack?! so please [edit] the question to identify the state.